# React js - how to assign result of a function to a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I have a question about react
currently in my app I want to get some data from server, and set default value of input, all of pulling is done in a function, but when I'm trying set state equal to function looks like react is thinking that I'm assigning function to state as a result on every input change state is being updated with function ignoring actual typing, is there a way to get past this?

Here is code for render part of component:

```
{metaList["properties"] &&
  metaList["properties"].map((item, idx) => (
    <label key={idx} style={{ display: "block", marginBottom: "20px" }}>
      {item.name + ":"}
      <div style={{ display: "none" }}>
        {this.findMeta()
          ? (this.state.properties[item.name] = this.findMeta())
          : ""}
        {this.state.properties[item.name]
          ? this.state.properties[item.name]
          : (this.state.properties[item.name] = "")}
      </div>
      <input
        name={item.name}
        placeholder={item.name}
        value={this.state.properties[item.name]}
        onChange={this.handleInputChangeProperties}
        style={{
          marginLeft: "20px"
        }}
      />
    </label>
  ))
}
```

`this.findMeta` is function I'm trying to call, nothing is special in it, function returns one variable as a string to get field filled.

Comment: You should not assign values to state directly on render, and you should not mutate state directly either.

Comment: Can you please tell what should I do then?

Comment: If you want to get some data from the server, it's a good idea to do that in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook and set the result in state. The render method should just derive JSX from your state and props.

Comment: why u not change the state in ur findmeta method? this is basicly the comon way and your snipped is kind of confusing me does this "handleInputChangeProperties" work? i know it more so "(e) => handleInputChangeProperties(e)"

Comment: You have to use this.setState({this.state.properties[item.name]:this.findMeta()})

Comment: StefanBD, I cant setstate in function because function is being called in render. Setting state will result in a render loop and will throw an error